# How to override or reset bootstrap styles with default browser's styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

**--------------------------------------------**

**Updated to clarify my question**

As in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/30x0pdzx/1/, I would like to make the second fieldset showing as the default browser renders here https://jsfiddle.net/1b0hxruq/1/

**--------------------------------------------**

I would like to override or reset the bootstrap styles of fieldset that have class `no-bootstrap`

```
<fieldset class="no-bootstrap">
    <legend></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Currently, bootstrap has styles for fieldset are

```
fieldset {
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

So what should I do to override (or reset) it to `default` browser styles?

```
fieldset.no-bootstrap {
    min-width: ???;
    padding: ???;
    margin: ???;
    border: ???;
}
```

Thanks for your considering :)

Comment: Are you known with CSS or ? You can fill-in anything what you want to style it like you want. Allways make sure to make a new CSS file and load it below the original bootstrap file in your head, Or I dont understand what you mean with your question.

Comment: Clarify the question. It seems like you already know the answer, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You could also just put those after including bootstrap css, as mentioned below !important for any of them that don't take effect is the way to go

Comment: @ZimSystem I just edited my question, as I see in duplicate question, it just says about the resetting for display property. But my question is resetting all properties for the whole element that has styles in bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

Where you have those question marks, simply add whatever styles you like, and then either add `!important;` to them all, or else make sure that your CSS sheet is loading AFTER Bootstraps.

For example this:

```
fieldset.no-bootstrap {
  min-width: 200px !important;
  padding: 5px !important;
  margin: 20px !important;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Will work (or at least is *extremely* likely to)  no matter where you put it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to style it with specific values since I just want to use the `default` browser's styles

Comment: @Vu Nguyen - Unfortunately there is no way to do that. Apart from anything each browser will be different. I can only suggest you style it some way that you consider a compromise, or else load Bootstrap manually, and remove the portions that affect fieldsets.

Answer (score 0):

Your overridden style should come after the code you want to override. So put bootstrap source before your personal css.

Also it's possible to use ! Important tag to override any specific style though it's not recommended to use it often.

It should be like this :

. Class{
    Color: red ! Important 
}

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not my question. I just updated it for clearer :D